Min Max Scaling of Frequency Domain
I have this spectrogram, especially I have the signal in time domain:

How do I perform Min Max Scaling over frequency while still in time domain?
I don't have problem if I perform Min Max scaling if it's the amplitude or the time (basically it's resample). But, the frequency, how can I do that?
In this picture we can safely say that the max is about 3100 Hz, I want rescale that frequency into 0 to 1, where 1 represent 3100 Hz while still in time domain.

What you're describing is Min-Max Normalization.
The formula for this is:
$X' = \cfrac{X_i - \min(X)}{\max(X)-\min(X)}$
where $X'$ is your normalized value, $X_i$ is your frequency value at time $i$, and $X$ is your range of frequency values over your time domain.
Suppose here at your max is 3100Hz and your min is 2900Hz. At time = 0 seconds, the frequency is 3000Hz.
So your normalized value of that would be:
$X'=\cfrac{3000 - 2900}{3100-2900}=0.5$
3100Hz would be 1 and 2900Hz would be 0.
However, from what I can see in your signal, it looks rather noisy at the start so I don't know if you can say for certain that your min and max values are indeed 2900Hz and 3100Hz respectively.
